# jquery.typer.js is not working on ie7 to ie9 versions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with the jquery.typer.js which isnot displaying the texts as it shows on other browsers like firefox, chrome, safari. I have created the demo of the work on jsfiddle. My main issue is that i want the typer.js to work as it works well on non-ie-browsers.

Here is the code that i am using for typewritter effect.

```
<div class="bubble_wrap">
 <div class="bubble"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var win = $(window),
    foo = $('.bubble');
    foo.typer(['<h2><span>Hey!</span><br> I create hand-forged web 2.0/3.0/ responsive   websites, illustrations and do html/css/html5/css3 slicings....</h2> ', '<h2><span>I </span><br>love doing vector arts, playing games and listening music in spare time.</h2>', '<h2>I am <span><br>Rajesh Kr. Das</span> working in IXOD as UI/Ux Designer <br>&amp; <br>Front-end Developer.</h2>']);
</script>
```

The full working example that works well on all modern browsers but fails to load on ie7 to ie9 link is on jsfiddle.

Link of the example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/razeshzone/CHbLz/6/)

I am again telling that the output doesnt show up like other browsers on ie-browsers 7 to 9, instead displays undefined message.

My question wasnot answered previously so i am again posting it in detail so that i can get the solution this time.

Comment: OT: congrats! i think you asked question #5,000,000

Comment: yes i asked again the same question that was removed lastly. waiting to get some solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are problem in `setTimeout(typetext, options.duration/10,i);`

IE 7 - 9 does not recognize third param i.

Solution is:

```
setTimeout(function(){typetext(i)}, options.duration/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the second **timer** variable should be

```
setTimeout(function(){typetext(i)}, options.delay);
```